# What is $Z$ such that $e^X e^Y e^{-X}=e^Z $?

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, exponential-function, lie-groups, lie-algebras

We know that $e^Z = e^X e^Y$ can be solved using Dynkin's formula.

I am thinking of how to similarly find $Z$ for the product in title. Do not need the actual answer, a hint suffices!

Comment: Damn! I made a mistake! Edited.

Answer (score 4):

By the [Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_important_lemma) we have
$$e^{X} e^{Y} e^{-X}= e^{Y+\left[X,Y\right]+\frac{1}{2!}[X,[X,Y]]+\frac{1}{3!}[X,[X,[X,Y]]]+\cdots}$$
The exponent $Z$ on the right hand side can be written as
$$Z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n!}~~\text{where}~~a_{n+1} = [X,a_n]~~\text{with}~~a_0 = Y$$
For the special case where $X$ and $Y$ commute then this simplifies to $e^Y = e^Z$. As pointed out by John below in general $Z=Y$ is not the only solution as the [matrix logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix#Existence) is not unique.

Comment: You only have $e^Z  =e^Y$.

Comment: @JohnMa Fair point. It's just *one* solution. Should have been more clear about that.